# When light ray travels from rarer medium to denser medium with angle of incidence =0 , does its speed or direction changes?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, density

The speed of the light will change , it doesn't remain constant and it will decreases , but what about the direction of light, will it change ?

Comment: What does Snell's law $n_1\sin\alpha_1=n_2\sin\alpha_2$ tell you when $\alpha_1=0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

[Snell's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law) says that
$$n_1\sin\theta_1=n_2\sin\theta_2.$$ If the angle of incidence $\theta_1$ is zero, the right-hand side must also vanish, so we must have $\theta_2=0$ and indeed have no change in the direction of the light. In theory we could also have $n_1/n_2\to\infty$, but that does not happen in practice.

Answer (score 1):

**No it doesn't.** Here's a diagram illustrating the effect of varying the angle of incidence:

[image]

And again, like others have mentioned, qualitatively we can use Snell's law to  show that generally when $\theta_1=0$, $\theta_2=0$, which means there's no deviation.